# SQL Error - not unique table / alias

Tags: sql

I am trying to join 2 tables by date, and then I want to use the Temperature specified on a certain category. This is my current SQL code:

```
SELECT id, pasnummer, datum1
FROM transacties1, knmidata
INNER JOIN knmidata ON knmidata.datum = transacties1.datum1
WHERE MinTemp < 100 AND category='actief'
```

> Error: 1066: knmidata is not specified.

I just renamed knmidata so name is unique. I appreciate if someone would help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried for the comma separated table join but added INNER JOIN again, that causes the error. Removing the second table from the `FROM` clause will solve the issue.

```
SELECT id, pasnummer, datum1 
FROM transacties1 -- , knmidata   is not required here
INNER JOIN knmidata ON knmidata.datum = transacties1.datum1 
WHERE MinTemp < 100 AND category = 'actief';
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this - the change is where you include the tables in the `FROM` section, you don't need the `knmidata` before the `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  pasnummer, 
  datum1 
FROM 
  transacties1 INNER JOIN knmidata 
    ON knmidata.datum = transacties1.datum1 
WHERE 
  MinTemp < 100 
  AND category='actief'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

I see no reason to include the `knmidata` table twice.  So, try this:

```
SELECT id, pasnummer, datum1
FROM transacties1 INNER JOIN
     knmidata
     ON knmidata.datum = transacties1.datum1
WHERE MinTemp < 100 AND category = 'actief';
```